# Workflow for converting .pb files to .tflite

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

**Overview**

I know this subject has been discussed many times, but I am having a hard time understanding the workflow, or rather, the variations of the workflow.

For example, imagine you are installing TensorFlow on Windows 10. The main goal being to train a custom model, convert to TensorFlow Lite, and copy the converted .tflite file to a Raspberry Pi running TensorFlow Lite.

The confusion for me starts with the conversion process. After following along with multiple guides, it seems TensorFlow is often install with pip, or Anaconda. But then I see [detailed tutorials](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi#step-2-build-tensorflow-from-source) which indicate it needs to be built from source in order to convert from TensorFlow models to TFLite models.

To make things more interesting, I've also seen models which are converted via Python scripts [as seen here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api).

**Question**

So far I have seen 3 ways to do this conversion, and it could just be that I don't have a grasp on the full picture. Below are the abbreviated methods I have seen:

1. Build from source, and use the TensorFlow Lite Optimizing Converter (TOCO):

   `bazel run --config=opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite ...`
2. Use the TensorFlow Lite Converter Python API:

   ```
   converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
   tflite_model = converter.convert()

   with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(tflite_model)
   ```
3. Use the tflite_convert CLI utilities:

   `tflite_convert --saved_model_dir=/tmp/mobilenet_saved_model --output_file=/tmp/mobilenet.tflite`

I *think I understand that options 2/3 are the same, in the sense that the tflite_convert utility is installed, and can be invoked either from the command line, or through a Python script. But is there a specific reason you should choose one over the other?

And lastly, what really gets me confused is option 1. And maybe it's a version thing (1.x vs 2.x)? But what's the difference between the TensorFlow Lite Optimizing Converter (TOCO) and the TensorFlow Lite Converter. It appears that in order to use TOCO you would have to build TensorFlow from source, so is there is a reason you would use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the output from different conversion methods, as long as the parameters remain the same. The Python API is better if you want to generate TFLite models in an automated way (for eg a Python script that's run periodically).

The TensorFlow Lite Optimizing Converter (TOCO) was the first version of the TF->TFLite converter. It was recently deprecated and replaced with a [new converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#new_in_tf_22) that can handle more ops/models. So I wouldn't recommend using `toco:toco` via bazel, but rather use `tflite_convert` as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline).

You should never *have* to build the converter from source, unless you are making some changes to it and want to test them out.